# Issue with Navigating to other page in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently working on implementing a redirection to a confirmation page once the submission process becomes successful (i.e., when a boolean flag, `onSubmit`, turns true). However, I am encountering an error when utilizing the navigation method. My project involves the use of the `react-router-dom` library.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; // Import useEffect
import axios from 'axios';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { Link, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './mainpage.css';
import './Confirmation';

const Mainpage = () => {
  const apiKey = '******';
  const baseId = '***********';
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
  });

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `https://api.airtable.com/v0/${baseId}/Users`,
        {
          records: [
            {
              fields: {
                name: formData.name,
                email: formData.email,
                phoneNumber: auth.currentUser.phoneNumber,
                address: formData.address,
                ocation: formData.location,
                fssai: formData.fssai,
                ResturantName: formData.ResturantName,
                Password: formData.Password,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );

      console.log('Data sent to Airtable:', response.data);
      
      // Handle success, show a confirmation message, or redirect the user.
      setSubmitted(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending data to Airtable:', error);
      // Handle the error, display an error message to the user, or perform error recovery.
    }  
  };

  if(submitted = true){
    Navigate('./Confermation');
  }

  const logout = () => {
    auth.signOut();
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <center>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name">Enter your Full Name:</label>
            <input
              ********rest of code
  );
};

export default Mainpage;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Navigate` is a React component and ***must*** be rendered in order to have any effect. In React we don't call the component functions directly, they are expressed in terms of JSX and React handles calling them at the right time (*e.g. when the component is being rendered to the DOM*).

```
if (submitted) {
  return <Navigate to="./confermation" />;
}
```

Typically though you would just use the `useNavigate` hook and issue an ***imperative*** navigation action directly in the handler.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; // Import useEffect
import axios from 'axios';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { Link, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './mainpage.css';
import './Confirmation';

const Mainpage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        ....
      );

      console.log('Data sent to Airtable:', response.data);
      
      // Handle success, show a confirmation message, or redirect the user.
      navigate("./confermation"); // <-- imperative navigation
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending data to Airtable:', error);
      // Handle the error, display an error message to the user, or perform error recovery.
    }   
   
  };

  const logout = () => {
    auth.signOut();
  };    

  return (
    ....
  );
};

export default Mainpage;
```

Comment: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Comment: shows this error

Comment: @TechnoHub You need to render your app within a router component so all `Link`, `Route`, etc components, and the React-Router hooks have a routing context available to them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems based on the code you shared in your question that the use of the hook provided by react-router-dom called 'useNavigate' is what you need.

this example is pulled from the documentation [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function useLogoutTimer() {
  const userIsInactive = useFakeInactiveUser();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userIsInactive) {
      fake.logout();
      navigate("/session-timed-out");
    }
  }, [userIsInactive]);
}
```

this way you can keep your basic setup without needing to change much else (notice how the hook is brought in and then the 'navigate' function is extracted and called with a string representing the desired path)